# Azure Bot fails after a time

Tags: azure, botframework, bots

I am creating a chatbot in a web channel. This is only to learn how it works. I created all servicess I need in Azure:  Web App Bot, App Service, App Service plan and Cognitive Services (LUIS.AI). It's all working correctly, all in same region.
I have all configurations correcly and when I deploy, it works perfectly. But few hours later (I didn't touch nothing), when I try to talk whit bot, I get an error: couldn't send. You can check here: https://zapateria-bot.azurewebsites.net/

When I check in Insights what is happening, I can see is like a permissions error:

> A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task
>   or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved
>   exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread. Operation returned an
>   invalid status code 'Unauthorized'

But remember, it worked before and I didn't touch nothing...

If I re-deploy again the bot works again...

What it's happenend?

The error call stack:

> System.AggregateException:
>   Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ErrorResponseException:    at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotState+d__10.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Bot.Connector, Version=3.14.0.7, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)    at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotStateExtensions+d__11.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Bot.Connector, Version=3.14.0.7, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)    at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ConnectorStore+-LoadAsync>d__2.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.14.0.7, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)    at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.CachingBotDataStore+d__8.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.14.0.7, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)    at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.CachingBotDataStore+-LoadAsync>d__6.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.14.0.7, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)    at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.BotDataBase`1+d__16.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.14.0.7, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)

Comment: It's looks like a SDK 3.13.1 version error. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4315

Just seen an update of Microsoft.Bot.Builder and Microsoft.Bot.Connector to 3.14.1.1, I try to update and check the behavior in a few hours.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, I checked your site, sometimes I get `couldn't send` error in webchat and **502 Bad Gateway** in f12 developer tools network tab. Did you get **502 Bad Gateway** error?

Comment: @JasonSowers, yes, it's the same problem. I did not find yesterday, sorry :(